# App's manual Package instalation

Tags: community, package, package-install, org, developer-org

Is it possible to download package and install it in different org without going throw security review in AppExchange? I mean, for testing purposes, download package drom original and install it manually (not from AppExcange) in other Salesforce org?

Thank You!

Best regards,
Juozas

Answer (score 1):

You can do a URL installation but you must first know the `SubscriberPackageVersionId` and Password (if required).

A SOQL using Tooling API to retrieve the `SubscriberPackageVersionId` from your source Salesforce environment i.e package already installed.

```
select SubscriberPackageVersionId from InstalledSubscriberPackage where Id = '<InsertId>'
```

Using the `SubscriberPackageVersionId` you can inject it into a request to install package URL within your target environment:

```
https://<instance>/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=SubscriberPackageVersionId/
```